# Entry name 'XPP3_1.1.4c_VERSION' collided

Tags: java, android, gradle, stripe-payments

I'm try to use stripe api in an android app, but when I set the dependency

```
    implementation "com.stripe:stripe-android:14.5.0";
```

I'm getting this error when I try to run the project

```
Entry name 'XPP3_1.1.4c_VERSION' collided
```

Any ideas what it's that?

Comment: I see you have a github issue on stripe-android too and someone replied this is likely due to CometChat PRO SDK: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/2637#issuecomment-656705873

Comment: well, I will do that